# Picasso on custom listview

Tags: java, android, listview, imageview, picasso

I'm a beginner with android and am trying to use the image from google places API to my custom listview. I am trying to do this using Picasso. I can get the text no problem but when I'm trying to attach the image from the url it gives me an "Target must not be null" error. Any comments/help/suggestions is appreciated.

My custom listrow places_layout.xml:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:weightSum="1">
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/placeicon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"/>
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/placeinfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/placeicon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/placeicon" />
     </RelativeLayout>
```

My Async PostExecute code:

```
    ImageView places_icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.placeicon);

    venuesfound = (ArrayList) parsedataFound(result);
            ArrayList<String> venuesList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i<venuesfound.size();i++){
                if(venuesfound.get(i).getImageURL() != null){
                    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                            .load(venuesfound.get(i).getImageURL())
                            .into(places_icon);
                }
                venuesList.add(venuesfound.get(i).getName()
                        + "\nOpen: " + venuesfound.get(i).getOpenNow()
                        + "\n(" + venuesfound.get(i).getCategory() + ")");
            }
            placesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.places_list);
            placesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(DisplayPlacesActivity.this, R.layout.places_layout, R.id.placeinfo, venuesList);
            placesList.setAdapter(placesAdapter);
```

Logcat:

```
     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
        at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:618)
        at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)
        at com.example.johnchy.samplegui.DisplayPlacesActivity$dataRequest.onPostExecute(DisplayPlacesActivity.java:102)
        at com.example.johnchy.samplegui.DisplayPlacesActivity$dataRequest.onPostExecute(DisplayPlacesActivity.java:56)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Again, any help is appreciated!

Comment: where is `com.example.johnchy.samplegui.DisplayPlacesActivity$dataRequest.onPostExecute(DisplayPlacesActivity.java:102)` ?

Comment: Thanks for responding! I believe that's the picasso line on Async onPostExecute code: Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                            .load(venuesfound.get(i).getImageURL())
                            .into(places_icon); It's on the second block of code

Comment: then check the values with your debugger, something is `null` in this line. I would guess `places_icon` is null, since it is the target

Comment: That's actually what I found weird. The first line of that second block of code is instantiating what the logcat is saying null. I'm not sure why it would suddenly lose that reference. Or maybe I'm looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: I guess the problem is, you try to find the corresponding element in your ACTIVITY-View, since you are using the activity method. You need to use the `findViewById` on the inflated `listrow places_layout.xml` view

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. Can you clarify a little bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you try to attach the image to an `ImageView`, that is not there yet. Since you want to show the image in your list, you need to move the attachment into the adapter, since this is where you create the new `ImageView`. You will need to create a new `ArrayAdapter` for this purpose:

```
public class PicassoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public PicassoAdapter(List<String> urls, Context context){
        super(context, 0, urls);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        PlaceViewHolder holder;
        //ListView tries to reuse invisible Row-Views to save memory, thats why this method can be called with null OR actually a ready View
        if(convertView == null){
            //in this case we need to create a new View
            //create a holder Object that we will attach to the view
            holder = new PlaceViewHolder();
            //in this line we actually create a new row from the xml-file
            convertView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.places_layout, parent, false);
            //we attach the Image- and Text-View to our holder, so we can access them in the next step
            holder.placeIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.placeicon);
            holder.placeInfo = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.placeinfo);
            convertView.setTag(holder)
        } else {
            //if the view is already created, simply get the holder-object
            holder = (PlaceViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        //I assume the URL is a String, if you need another Type, simply change it here and in class declaration
        String url = getItem(position);
        Picasso.with(getContext())
                        .load(url)
                        //now we have an ImageView, that we can use as target
                        .into(holder.placeIcon);
         //you can set the info here
         holder.placeInfo.setText("test");
         }
    }

    //we need this class as holder object
    public static class PlaceViewHolder {
        private ImageView placeIcon;
        private TextView palceInfo;
    }
}
```

now you can use this adapter in your List:

```
placesList.setAdapter(new PicassoAdapter(urls, DisplayPlacesActivity.this));
```

beware, that the performance of this code may be very bad, since we try to load the image on the UI-Thread, but I think it's ok as an example

Comment: Thanks! that worked! But you're correct, it did slow down my application a little bit. Do you have any suggestions on how to make this more efficient?

Comment: you can try to load the Images in your async call and put the icons as  `byte[]` into a `List` and call the adapter with that list instead of Url's. I'm not familiar with Picasso, but I guess they have some function to get an icon as `byte[]`. Even with that, displaying multiple large images on the screen is a heavy task for smart-phones in medium to lower price segment

Comment: Thanks! I will try that.